# Set Windows Hello Pin for local users with .NET

Tags: windows-hello

I am currently trying to write a .NET application that generates a Windows Hello PIN for my local user and changes this PIN every 5 minutes.
Is there a way to set and customise the Windows Hello pin using .NET?

searching in library Windows.Security.Credentials are not successful for me.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible as the "Windows Hello" feature relies on a microsoft account etc. and isn't really managed locally, but I'm not sure. Wouldn't it be a option for you to use a local user account instead of Windows Hello? It would be "easier" to change the user credentials as they are saved in the local SAM.

Comment: Windows Hello PIN can be used for Microsoft accounts and local accounts: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/log-in-with-pin-on-a-local-account/10a5bccc-441e-43b9-9dda-7f84dcf21730